# How to fix the python code run in vsCode ,the data crawled is Chinese garbled,but not in python idle directly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, web-crawler, output

I wrote a piece of web crawler code, which was used to crawl the youdao dictionary for translation. When running in vscode, the output was garbled. When running directly on python idle, the output was normal .What should I do?

I have tried to set  encoding mode to utf-8 ,gb2312 or gbk,but it didn't work.

```
from urllib import request
from urllib import parse
import json
content = input("请输入你要查找的字:")

url = " http://fanyi.youdao.com/translate?smartresult=dict&smartresult=rule"

data = {}
data['i'] = content
data['from'] = 'AUTO'
data['to'] = 'AUTO'
data['smartresult'] = 'dict'
data['client'] = 'fanyideskweb'
data['doctype'] = 'json'
data['version'] = '2.1'
data['keyfrom'] = 'fanyi.web'
data['action'] = 'FY_BY_CLICKBUTTION'
data = parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')

header = {}
header['Referer'] = 'http://fanyi.youdao.com/?keyfrom=dict2.index'
header['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.25 Safari/537.36 Core/1.70.3650.400 QQBrowser/10.4.3341.400'


req = request.Request(url = url, headers = header)

response = request.urlopen(req, data = data)

result_str = response.read().decode('utf-8')

result_dict = json.loads(result_str)
print(result_dict)


print('翻译的结果是：%s' % result_dict['translateResult'][0][0]['tgt'])
```

if I input 'love',I expect the output of 'love' to be '爱'.When I run the above code in python idle ，it is normal.But run in the vscode ,it is garbled.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Put encoding type at the first line of your script as a comment line, i.e.    #  -*- coding = utf-16  -*-

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I try it,but it doesn't work.

Comment: @liulangya what version of Python is this?

Comment: @Brett Cannon 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the terminal has a different encoding than the one in IDLE and that's causing the different results.

If you can upgrade to Python 3.7 then that may fix it as work was done to use more sensible defaults for terminal encodings in that release.

Comment: Thanks for your precious suggestion.I try it,it does work.Really thank you.But I Really  don't konw why?Can you explain it?

Comment: @ Brett Cannon Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @liulangya basically every terminal has an encoding it supports for text, e.g. UTF-8. Before Python 3.7 we tried to work with what we know about the terminal, but sometimes that info is incomplete or wrong. Starting in Python 3.7 we try to force the terminal to UTF-8 if not specified to simplify things.